# Htaccess Url Rewriting on Codeigneter project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Can i transforme this url for exemple this http://test.exemple.com/controller_nam/methode_name/parameter_name/**parametre_value** to this url 
http://test.exemple.com/**parametre_value**  using .htaccess  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that using htaccess but you can do that with routes.php (in config folder) file

Like this:

```
$route['(\d+)'] = "controller_name/method_name/$1/";
```

And $1 is the parameter from url in decimal

If you need pass string as parameter, then try this:

```
$route['([a-z-]+)'] = "controller_name/method_name/$1/";
```

and $1 will be that string from url

So for example if you have controller Home and there is:

```
public function methodname($parameter) {}
```

Use routing like:

```
$route['([a-z-]+)'] = "home/methodname/$1/";
```

In url: example.com/this_is_parameter
In method *methodname* will be $parameter = "this_is_parameter"

Comment: can you explain more please because i'm new in codeigneter , can you give me more details please Daniel ?

Comment: application/config/routes.php
Put this code in this file, and change "controller_name" on your controller name and "method_name" on your method name

I edited my answer look up

Comment: really you have saved me , thanks Daniel it's verry kind of you  :)

Comment: sorry i don't have 15  in reputation to confirme this response  , really sorry

Comment: doesn't metter, hope i help you